# How do I change the application name after the project has been made?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

I created a new Blank App (Universal Windows) project titled "Bork". My top level folder is named Bork, my project folder is named Bork, and my .sln file is named Bork. When I compile and install it is named "Bork".

[image: Application]
[image: Launch]

How do I change it so that when it is installed the program is named "Schwindig"?

[image: Desire]

Comment: Check at the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Change the display name in the `Package.appxmanifest` file before you build and install the app.

If you open the file in the designer in Visual Studio, you should look for the display name under the `Application` tab. Alternatively, you could right-click on the `.appxmanifest` file and choose "View Code" to edit the `DisplayName` attribute of the `VisualElements` element in the XML manually.

[What's the difference between Properties/DisplayName element and VisualElements@DisplayName attribute in .appxmanifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760695/whats-the-difference-between-properties-displayname-element-and-visualelements/40762059)